# Does SonarQube analyse Maven dependencies by default?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I know SonarQube analyses both source code and bytecode (jars and .class files).

Does it only analyse the jar of the "main" project, or does it also analyse the jars of its Maven dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jars aren't analyzed. 
The source code and compiled classes of your project are analyzed, and during that analysis, the project's dependencies are used to get a little more information about the calls your project is making. But the jars aren't analyzed.